# How many $\alpha \in S_n$ are there with $\alpha^2 = 1$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

How many $\alpha \in S_n$ are there with $\alpha^2 = 1$?

I want to use just linear algebra, I have done it using combinatorics but in class that does not work, can I get a little help? What I know is that

(i j) = (j i) and (i j)(k I) =
(k l)(i j).

Comment: Hint: Try it for $S_3,$ and $S_4$.  Essentially, you are looking for the number of permutations of order two:  See if there is a pattern?

Comment: @amWhy I see that they used combinatorics there, is that the only way?

Comment: This is not a linear algebra problem.  Ultimately, it is a group theory problem about the symmetric group $S_n$, and combinatorics is closely related, a tool, as you will.  The question is not a linear algebra question.

Comment: Ohhh my bad, I thought it as a linear algebra problem beacuase I saw it on a book about it, but I got it, thank you!

Comment: Also see [How many $\alpha \in S)n$ are such that $\alpha^2$ = 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020671/how-many-alpha-in-s-n-are-there-with-alpha2-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)